# WPF Distorted Shape

Tags: c#, wpf, distortion

I need to add distortion effects to a shape in WPF.

For example, I want to distort a **shape with spikes** such that it would look as shown below:

[image: Distorted circle]

Comment: And where is your code you tried to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you need just static shape, then you can also use Path. Advantage of Path is, that you can create (or convert any image to) vectors with Inkscape and then export it to XAML Path.

Comment: Welcome to SO Fritz! Your answer would probably be more complete and helpful with an example of using a Path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a Polygon, it would take a bit of work to get what you're looking for but it could be done. This [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/polygon-in-wpf/) has a simple demo of how to use the Polygon tag.